# Backing up DynamoDB tables via data pipeline vs manually creating a json for dynamoDB

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline, cost-management

I need to back up a few DynamoDB tables which are not too big for now to S3. However, these are tables another team uses/works on but not me. These back ups need to happen once a week, and will only be used to restore the DynamoDB tables in disastrous situations (so hopefully never). 
I saw that there is a way to do this by setting up a data pipeline, which I'm guessing you can schedule to do the job once a week. However, it seems like this would keep the pipeline open and start incurring charges. So I was wondering, if there is a significant cost difference between backing the tables up via the pipeline and keeping it open, or creating something like a powershellscript that will be scheduled to run on an EC2 instance, which already exists, which would manually create a JSON mapping file and update that to S3.
Also, I guess another question is more of a practicality question. How difficult it is to backup dynamoDB tables to Json format. It doesn't seem too hard but wasn't sure. Sorry if these questions are too general.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are working under the assumption that Data Pipeline keeps the server up forever?  That is not the case.

For instance, you have defined a Shell Activity, after the activity completes, the server will terminate. (You may manually set the termination protection.  [Ref.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html)

Since you only run a pipeline once a week, the costs are not high.

If you run a cron job on ec2 instance, that instance needs to up when you want to run the backup - and that could be a point of failure.

Incidentally, Amazon provides a Datapipeline sample on [how to export data from dynamodb](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html).

Comment: The EC2 instance I mentioned is already going to be constantly running as it is doing other jobs as well which must continually run. 
I was just afraid that doing a pipeline job once a week, but keeping that pipeline created but unused would incur a large cost. I guess I could theoretically schedule the data pipeline to be created each week, do the job and then delete it.

Comment: It incurs $1 per month just for pipeline.  https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/pricing/   - and the cost of running an EC2 instance during the task execution.  If you set the frequency of task to weekly, Datapipeline provisions a resource at that time, runs the task - and when completed terminates the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the pipeline cost page, and it says "For example, a pipeline that runs a daily job (a Low Frequency activity) on AWS to replicate an Amazon DynamoDB table to Amazon S3 would cost $0.60 per month". So I think I'm safe.